# Copying one row's data to another row with Laravel's Eloquent (or Fluent)

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, fluent

Here's the deal. I've set up my database with two tables that are more or less as follows (actually, my table is much more complex, but this is the gist):

**TABLE `elements`**

- id
- data

**TABLE `element_drafts`**

- id
- element_id
- data

As you might be able to guess from the names, the second table contains rows that are drafts of rows in the first table. (Don't worry about recommending better ways to do the drafts =) my tables are more complex than shown, and having a drafts table is the best solution atm).

I've set up a relationship between the two tables so that I can do things like this:

```
// Get all of the elements along with their draft rows
$elements_with_drafts = Element::with('drafts')->all();
```

I'm also able to select only the elements that HAVE draft rows by doing this:

```
$elements_with_drafts = Element::with('drafts')
    ->whereIn('id', function($query)
    {
        $query->select('element_id')->from('element_drafts');
    })
    ->get();
```

But there's one thing that I'd like to do that I can't figure out: copying the draft values to their parent element.

### In the end, my goal is to copy over all of the element_drafts['data'] values to their parent element['data'] field via a single query.

I'm not totally sure that this is even possible. Is it?

My guess is that somehow it might be done like this:

```
$elements_with_drafts = Element::with('drafts')
    ->whereIn('id', function($query)
    {
        $query->select('element_id')->from('element_drafts');
    })
    ->update(array("data" => function($query)
    {
        // Somehow select the draft value?
    });
```

I feel like I'm really close, but I'm not quite sure how to do what I want. Any ideas?

Note: obviously this could be accomplished relatively easily with a `foreach` loop, but I'm hoping for a solution that is just a single query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like @Ben's, only he made some mistakes:

```
DB::statement('UPDATE elements e
    JOIN element_drafts d ON e.id = d.element_id
    SET e.data = d.data');
```

In fact you can use `Query Builder` too:

```
DB::table('elements as e')
    ->join('element_drafts as d', 'd.element_id', '=', 'e.id')
    ->update(['e.data' => DB::raw('d.data')]);
```

Both will work just the same.

Mind that it will set `e.data` to `d.data` of first row joined (in case you have more drafts than one per element).

Answer (score 2):

```
DB::statement('UPDATE elements e
               JOIN drafts d
               SET e.data = d.data WHERE e.id = d.element_id');
```

EDIT: Check deczo's answer for a Query Builder solution.

Comment: Okay, dumb question (I'm not a database guru by any means), in this statement are you basically on the fly creating a variable named 'e' that points to the elements table (and the same for drafts and d)? I didn't realize you could on the fly create variables in SQL statements. Sweet!

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting an error that says "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;" Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah i made a syntactic mistake, fixed it.